# symfony5 translation:update result not as expected

Tags: symfony, translate, symfony5

i jave a messages.de.yaml File:

test: Test

**just.another.test: Test 2**

When i do php bin/console translation:update --force en  --output-format=yaml i get:

messages.en.yaml
test: Test

**just.another.test: __just.another.test**

Why is on the right after : not the "Test 2" for the translator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `__` is to make it obvious that it's a untranslated string (and you can change it with the `--prefix` option).
When updating the translation files, the translation *keys* are the messages as they went through the system, in your case, rather than phrases you used keywords. The translation *values* are just the keys plus the prefix.
You then have to "fill" those translations, the system has no way of "making up" the translation on its own nor copies the value from the original language, that would make a pending translation harder to spot.

But if the key was missing altogether in the file, it would use the message from the `fallback_locale`.

So, in this instance, the first message must have been already translated in another `translation:update` run, while the second is new and pending translation.